# is Facebook app approval required for share link app_id?

Tags: html, facebook, share, meta-tags, app-id

I am looking to customize the Facebook share button with a custom website icon (the 16x16 one) when a user opens the dialog window to share an article. As I understand, it requires a Facebook app_id and then setting the icon in the app_id settings.

My question is, does the Facebook app need to be sent to "approval" for this to work? Or is that only required for actual apps that are used on Facebook? Because what I am doing is not an actual app, I just need the icon customized that users will see when they post something. Would it work just going from sandbox to live without submitting to approval?